# Editing is not working in wordpress plugin stylesheet

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a wordpress plugin which adds a style sheet. I am using the following code:

```
<?php 
add_action('admin_print_styles','add_my_style');
function add_my_style() {
wp_enqueue_style('CSS', plugins_url( '/css/tableplugin.css', __FILE__ ));
}
?>
```

When I edit the `tableplugin.css` file, the changes are not reflected on my site. How to I edit the CSS file in wordpress plugin?

Comment: I give ctrl+f5 in my site. Its working now. Sorry for disturbing you by asking this question..

Comment: You should delete the question then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try this code. I hope it will work for you.

```
function admin_style() {
   wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/css/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will works for you!

```
    <?php 
        add_action('admin_enqueue_styles','add_my_style');
        function add_my_style() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'CSS', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/tableplugin.cs', array(), '1.0' );
        }
        ?>
```

see this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/

Comment: What is the  difference between actions and filters? I studied theoretically.. anyone please say with example..